# Using CareKit in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, researchkit, carekit

I've been struggling with [CareKit](https://github.com/carekit-apple/CareKit) for past few days and I were unable to use CareKit in my SwiftUI project.
It would be so great if I could get a really really simple project on SwiftUI.

Also how can I use only one specific Card? for example only Task Card.

Comment: Have you been successful at using ResearchKit/CareKit with SwiftUI?